# Embedding fonts in inkscape

Tags: svg, fonts, inkscape

Does any body know what is the current status of embedding fonts into an svg file that is readable by inkscape. I find the lack of embedded fonts severely impedes portability of svg files, particular if sending the file to a person who doesn't have admin access on their machine and cannot install fonts.

I tried to follow the instructions given at this link:

[HOWTO: Embedding a font in a Linux Inkscape SVG document](http://fob.po8.org/node/663)

but have been unable to get it to work, this link also suggests that it is possible:

https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/83618

I, to be fair am trying to get this to work on windows, not linux (I don't have access to a linux machine right now). Does any one know of or have access to an actual svg file where this feature is working?

Comment: you should be able to open the file on a text editor or use the inkscape xml editor and follow the instructions [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg) and on a windows machine is probably easier to try the online converter [here](http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff2)

Comment: Hi There, I tried that already, with a converted font, and was unsuccessful.  I think the answer is that it is not supported in inkscape yet.

Answer (score 7):

I think I have found a workaround for this.

If there isn't too much text in the SVG, you can select all the text objects and `Path`-> `Object to Path`, then you can no longer edit the text, but the resulting file can be correctly parsed by any viewer even if the font is not installed.

If there're lots texts, this operation may increase the size of SVG file.

Comment: Hi Wesley.  I am aware of this solution, but it is the opposite of this that was interested in, I don't want to lose edit-ability of the text content.

Comment: @DouglasKastle Well, apparently that's not supported yet ...

Comment: Please see discussion below. We resolved that back in Jan 2015

Answer (score 1):

I got and answer over at [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43300/embedding-fonts-in-inkscape) from user [Paolo Gibellini](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/15703/paolo-gibellini):

In the current version of Inkscape seems not yet possible to embed SVG fonts (see also here a little example).

In 0.48 Release Notes:

> There is a known limitation where the list of glyphs in the dialog are not yet rendered in the selected font, but still in the system font

In 0.47 Release Notes there is a more detailed explanation of the limitations:

> As a SoC 2008 project, JucaBlues implemented initial parsing and rendering of SVG Fonts. You can design fonts within Inkscape, but using them to render text on the canvas is not yet supported. We are waiting for libpango to implement proper support of the user-fonts feature.

The render of SVG Fonts is not supported by Firefox or Internet Explorer, and Inkscape Wiki tell us that:

> SVG2.0 may replace SVG fonts by WOFF

(let's wait and see)